# interface Builder iOS - how to specify only iphone 5s layout with size classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, size-classes

Is there a way i can target only a iphone 5s layout using size classes ? From what i can tell the size classes are not specific to device because i found this in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html):
[image]

but i have a requirement to have a certain number of constraints of iphone 5s to be different constant. Do i have to do this programatically ?

Comment: i always design the storybaord using autolayout which supports all screen sizes.

Comment: yeah autolayout is fine but its not perfect.  i have a different look we want on 5s.

Comment: Check out this tutorial by Sam Davies http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial he shows how to use IB to specify different constraints, images etc for different size class combinations as well as how to preview your work directly in iB. You can likely do what you want in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to do so is to make outlets from the constraints and you can modify them programatically,
As Size classes are traits assigned to a user interface element, such as a screen or a view having two types regular and compact.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *search_button_distance;

[self.search_button_distance setConstant:100];
```